# Copying tinymce skin's directory using webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpacker

According to TinyMce's [Webpack file-loader](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/#webpackfile-loader) documentation, the following snippet will copy TinyMce's skins directory:

```
require.context(
  'file?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce!tinymce/skins',
  true,
  /.*/
);
```

I placed this snippet into `app/assets/javascript/tinymce.vue` right before my include statements for tinymce. Unfortunately, I get the following error thrown by `postcss` when I attempt to webpack compile:

```
% rails webpacker:compile

Webpacker is installed  
Using /repos/myapp/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
Compiling…
Compilation failed:
CssSyntaxError: /repos/myapp/js/skins/content/default/content.css:2:1: Unknown word
    at Input.error (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/input.js:130:16)
    at Parser.unknownWord (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:563:22)
    at Parser.other (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:168:12)
    at Parser.parse (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/parser.js:77:16)
    at parse (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/parse.js:17:12)
    at new LazyResult (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/lazy-result.js:60:16)
    at Processor.<anonymous> (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:138:12)
    at Processor.process (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/processor.js:117:23)
    at Function.creator.process (/repos/myapp/node_modules/postcss/lib/postcss.js:148:43)
    at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.processCss (/repos/myapp/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:65:21)
    at Object.processor (/repos/myapp/node_modules/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:11:18)
    at each (/repos/myapp/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:150:10)
    at arrayEach (/repos/myapp/node_modules/lodash/_arrayEach.js:15:9)
    at forEach (/repos/myapp/node_modules/lodash/forEach.js:38:10)
    at OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin.process (/repos/myapp/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:147:5)
    at compilation.hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.tapPromise.chunks (/repos/myapp/node_modules/last-call-webpack-plugin/src/index.js:178:28)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:8:17)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.additionalAssets.callAsync.err (/repos/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1311:36)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at hooks.optimizeTree.callAsync.err (/repos/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1307:32)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.seal (/repos/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1244:27)
    at hooks.make.callAsync.err (/repos/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:624:17)
    at _done (eval at create (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at _err1 (eval at create (/repos/myapp/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:32:22)
    at _addModuleChain (/repos/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1095:12)
    at processModuleDependencies.err (/repos/myapp/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1007:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:9)
```

`rails webpacker:compile` compiles to `public/packs` directory and the error message is referencing a directory that doesn't exist. Also of note, line 2 of `/node_modules/tinymce/skins/content/default/content.css`is simply part of a comment block in css:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) Tiny Technologies, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * Licensed under the LGPL or a commercial license.
 * For LGPL see License.txt in the project root for license information.
 * For commercial licenses see https://www.tiny.cloud/
 */
```

I think I need to use another loader (e.g `style-loader`) to compile the css... but I don't quite know how to do that using webpack's inline syntax.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `file-loader`'s documentation, I can specify the output path via [`outputPath`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader#outputpath).

As for webpack's `style-loader`, I learned you can disable other loaders by prefixing the desired the [inline syntax](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline) with an `!`.

```js
// copy tinymce's skins directory into public/packs
require.context(
  '!file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]&context=node_modules/tinymce&outputPath=js!tinymce/skins',
  true,
  /.*/
);
```

Comment: Where would this go in a Rails+Webpacker setup? There's no webpacker config file.

Comment: Found the spot to use that require.context, on the TinyMce.js file and it worked. Leaving this comment here if anyone else ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. This was our fix:

Remove `.css` from your `static_assets_extensions:` list in your `webpacker.yml`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, had that .css excluded from the list but still got that "unknown word" error.